# How can I remove dots from hand landmark in mediepipe

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, object-detection, mediapipe

I'm able to detect nail and palm with media pip and python but can't manage to extract the nail part. How can I select the part using media pipe

**I want to show only (4,8,12,16,20) these points and remove other white dots.**

[image]

Here is my code for hand detection

```
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import numpy as np
import uuid
import os
    
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
handConnection = [(4, 4), (8, 8), (12, 12), (16, 16), (20, 20)]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def main():
    hands = mp_hands.Hands(
    min_detection_confidence=0.7, min_tracking_confidence=0.7)
    hand_landmark_drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121, 22, 6), thickness=0, circle_radius=0)
    hand_connection_drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(250, 44, 90), thickness=15, circle_radius=15)

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, image = cap.read()
        image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.flip(image, 1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results_hand = hands.process(image)
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        if results_hand.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for idx, hand_landmarks in enumerate(results_hand.multi_hand_landmarks):
                
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                    image=image,
                    landmark_list=hand_landmarks,
                    connections=handConnection,
                    landmark_drawing_spec=hand_landmark_drawing_spec,
                    connection_drawing_spec=hand_connection_drawing_spec)

        cv2.imshow('Hand Tracking', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    hands.close()
    cap.release()

main()
```

How can I show or use from the image below (4,8,12,16,20). I want to place text over them. How I can achieve this or able to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to get each desired landmark points by one by and then you can use them easily. [Here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/python/solutions/hands.py) is the class you need to focus. In there, all the points are listed as:

[image]

so all you neeed to do is calling them by one by and using them. Here is my result and code:

[image]

```
import mediapipe as mp
import cv2
import numpy as np
import uuid
import os

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
drawSpecific = mp.solutions.hands
mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
handConnection = [(4, 4), (8, 8), (12, 12), (16, 16), (20, 20)]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def main():
    hands = mp_hands.Hands(min_detection_confidence=0.7,
                           min_tracking_confidence=0.7)
    hand_landmark_drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121, 22,
            6), thickness=5, circle_radius=0)
    hand_connection_drawing_spec = mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(250,
            44, 90), thickness=15, circle_radius=15)

    while cap.isOpened():
        (ret, image) = cap.read()
        image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.flip(image, 1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        (image_height, image_width, _) = image.shape

        results_hand = hands.process(image)
        image.flags.writeable = True
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        if results_hand.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for (idx, hand_landmarks) in \
                enumerate(results_hand.multi_hand_landmarks):
                color = (0xFF, 0, 0)

                center_coordinates1 = \
                    (hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.THUMB_TIP].x
                     * image_width,
                     hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.THUMB_TIP].y
                     * image_height)
                center_coordinates2 = \
                    (hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].x
                     * image_width,
                     hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.INDEX_FINGER_TIP].y
                     * image_height)
                center_coordinates3 = \
                    (hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP].x
                     * image_width,
                     hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.MIDDLE_FINGER_TIP].y
                     * image_height)
                center_coordinates4 = \
                    (hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.RING_FINGER_TIP].x
                     * image_width,
                     hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.RING_FINGER_TIP].y
                     * image_height)
                center_coordinates5 = \
                    (hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.PINKY_TIP].x
                     * image_width,
                     hand_landmarks.landmark[drawSpecific.HandLandmark.PINKY_TIP].y
                     * image_height)

                cv2.circle(image, (int(center_coordinates1[0]),
                           int(center_coordinates1[1])), 15, color, 5)
                cv2.circle(image, (int(center_coordinates2[0]),
                           int(center_coordinates2[1])), 15, color, 5)
                cv2.circle(image, (int(center_coordinates3[0]),
                           int(center_coordinates3[1])), 15, color, 5)
                cv2.circle(image, (int(center_coordinates4[0]),
                           int(center_coordinates4[1])), 15, color, 5)
                cv2.circle(image, (int(center_coordinates5[0]),
                           int(center_coordinates5[1])), 15, color, 5)

                # mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(
                    # image=image,
                    # landmark_list=hand_landmarks,
                    # connections=handConnection,
                    # landmark_drawing_spec=hand_landmark_drawing_spec,
                    # connection_drawing_spec=hand_connection_drawing_spec
                    # )

        cv2.imshow('Hand Tracking', image)

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    hands.close()
    cap.release()


main()
```